# The Left Slide Menu is not working (PFAirViewController)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently developing an `iOS app` with a **left sliding menu**. I use a template from this [link](https://github.com/TaPhuocHai/PHAirViewController/blob/master/README.md):  (btw, it is a greatly coded left sliding menu demo), and I prefer to use storyboard to design the UI.

Thus, I transplant the api from this `Github` link. I follow the instruction but I still got some fatal errors. Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/smzefkb1ud4982o/Fitness%20Main%20Framework.zip?dl=0) to a copy of my project. Could anyone help me the to solve the issue please.

**Here is the exception output displayed in the console:**

```
2014-12-01 16:08:21.654 Fitness Main Framework[10757:504122] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:

(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e8fb75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010477fbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d8772e -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 190
    3   Fitness Main Framework              0x0000000103fd196f -[PHAirViewController saveThumbnailImage:atIndexPath:] + 159
    4   Fitness Main Framework              0x0000000103fce560 -[PHAirViewController showAirViewFromViewController:complete:] + 752
    5   Fitness Main Framework              0x0000000103fd3841 -[ZZPersonalProfileTabVC leftButtonTouch] + 145
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010528063e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001053872c0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010538668f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001052c60e8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001052c6a13 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000105293791 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001052a085d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010527be9c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104dc49d1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104dba89d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104db9ed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104db9906 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001081009f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010527f1a0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    20  Fitness Main Framework              0x0000000103fd38d3 main + 115
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107c55145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Fix your formatting or probably nobody will answer you ! I do it instead of you good luck !

Comment: And you overwrite my formating ahh, good luck anyway :)

Comment: Oops.. I tried to edit it by myself but I just found that you revised for me... so sry :(

Comment: My Internet is probably lagging... I really appreciate your revising ...

Comment: I found your editing and I changed it back. It is much better hah.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to my question. It was a silly mistake, I mistakenly copy the viewdidload code to memeorylow function...  The api is great